# MSBuild, VS2008 solution and CI - what are the best practices?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, continuous-integration, mstest

I am setting up a CI system for VS2008/C# desktop project, nothing fancy, just a build/test cycle. CI will be running under Hudson using MSBuild/MSTest, but I can't seem to decide on a how to do a few things, maybe you can help me out?

My options for running the project in the CI are:

- Run the .sln directly from MSBuild
- Run the .csproj directly from MSBuild
- Create a separate MSBuild project referencing the .sln or .csproj as an MSBuild task
- Create a separate MSBuild project importing some stuff (property groups or item groups)
  from the .csproj

If I wouldn't need to run tests, I would most probably just used the 1st option (run the .sln with MSBuild). But I need to add a task for running the tests, so I can't seem to decide if I should add the task/target to the .csproj's or do it in a separate project. One thing I want to achieve is that when I change my .sln or one of the .csproj, ideally I shouldn't have to touch anything else to be able to keep running successfully in the CI.

Another question is around running the MSTest - is Exec task sufficient or should I write/use some MSTest task (can't seem find one on the .Net)

Answer (score 2):

The Test task is a built-in task for MSBuild in .NEt 3.5 Framework, as is code coverage. Just search on the BeforeTest and CoreTest-targets on MSDN. Not very hard, just include something like:

```
   <ItemGroup>
      <TestContainer Include="$(OutDir)\BuildTestProject.dll" />
   </ItemGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
      <MetaDataFile Include="$(SolutionRoot)\BuildTest.vsmdi" />
   </ItemGroup>

   <PropertyGroup>
      <RunConfigFile>$(SolutionRoot)\LocalTestRun.testrunconfig</RunConfigFile>
   </PropertyGroup>
```

should work..

Comment: Nope, can't seem to make it work. RunConfigFile is a property on a TestToolsTask, which is a part of Team Foundation Build. And TFS is not in the picture for me.

Comment: Ah, didn't know it was TFBuild only, in that case, you should indeed use MSTest by calling an Exec-task. Should be plenty of samples on the net.